# how can i add animation to tex in carousel?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have to add an animation to a caption on the carousel so when I scroll on to it the caption should fade in
I tried a lot of things but didn't get a satisfactory result

```css
.carousel-item {
  transition: transform 2.6s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end {
  transition: opacity 0s 2.6s;
}
```

Comment: im new to stack overflow if any issues in the Q plz neglect it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Abhishek. Usually with any page element animation can be achieved purely with CSS. I don't think this will work on a carousel as slides 2, 3, 4 etc will animate with slide 1 even though they're out of view. Do a search on `Codepen` or somewhere similar as I think you will find the task requires you to add some JavaScript. Hopefully it is easy to find some JS that can simply be copied and pasted.